# How to conditionally change WooCommerce billing address title if no separate shipping address is entered

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

My site has two options

- you can ship to the billing address
- you can enter a billing address and a separate delivery address, pretty standard.

---

If you enter both a billing and a *shipping* address during checkout, then in the order details page in My Account you can see both Billing address and Shipping address titles above the relevant addresses.

If you only enter a billing address during checkout, in the order details page in My Account you can only see 'Billing' address, the address isn't duplicated as the shipping address. No Shipping address is shown, so it looks strange.

---

> I would like to conditionally rename 'Billing address' to 'Billing & Shipping address' if the order has no separate shipping address.
>
> It would be beneficial to change it in the emails as well, as it would make more sense.

I have found this for renaming the title (I haven't tested it), but how can I do it conditionally?

```php
function wc_billing_field_strings( $translated_text, $text, $domain ) {
    switch ( $translated_text ) {
        case 'Billing address' :
            $translated_text = __( 'Billing & Shipping address', 'woocommerce' );
            break;
    }

    return $translated_text;
}
add_filter( 'gettext', 'wc_billing_field_strings', 20, 3 );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**My Account**

> https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/templates/order/order-details-customer.php
>
> - This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/order/order-details-customer.php.

Replace (line: [31](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/templates/order/order-details-customer.php#L31))

```php
<h2 class="woocommerce-column__title"><?php esc_html_e( 'Billing address', 'woocommerce' ); ?></h2>
```

With

```php
<h2 class="woocommerce-column__title">
<?php
// Show shipping = false    
if ( !$show_shipping ) {
    $title = 'Billing & Shipping address';      
} else {
    $title = 'Billing address';
}

esc_html_e( $title, 'woocommerce' );
?>
</h2>
```

---

**E-mail**

> https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/templates/emails/email-addresses.php
>
> - This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/emails/email-addresses.php.

Replace (line: [29](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/templates/emails/email-addresses.php#L29))

```php
<h2><?php esc_html_e( 'Billing address', 'woocommerce' ); ?></h2>
```

With

```php
<h2>
<?php 
// Billing_address
if ( !$order->needs_shipping_address() ) {
    $title = 'Billing & Shipping address';     
} else {
    $title = 'Billing address';
}

esc_html_e( $title, 'woocommerce' );
?>
</h2>
```

Comment: Thanks - not sure why I was trying to do this with a function rather than a child theme template... I think the email part will need to be done with a function though?

Comment: Thanks again, I was looking at the email templates in WooCommerce rather than the template files in the plugin.

Comment: @Lyall, updated for email. Note that you can add multiple checks (email template) based on the code used in the if condition like `wc_ship_to_billing_address_only()`, `$order->needs_shipping_address()` & `$shipping`

Comment: I can't seem to get the email to work - the first version you posted changed it correctly but it changed for everything, the updated version doesn't seem to change it? The My Account part works perfectly :)

Comment: Perfect - thank you! And thank you for the information regarding the other checks, I'll bear those in mind for the future.