# Edit view order page WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, templates, woocommerce

I would like to change the text on the view order page. Link is: /my-account/view-order/127482/

[image]

I would like to change the text Billing address to Shipping address. But only on this page. How can I do this?

Comment: This is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61526630/how-to-conditionally-change-woocommerce-billing-address-title-if-no-separate-shi/), get started and adjust your question where necessary if you cannot find a solution. 
The intention on stack overflow is to show what you've tried. [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: You need to [override Woocommerce templates via  your theme](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/)… The related template file is located in the Woocommerce plugin under `templates/order/order-details-customer.php`

Answer (score 1):

Add this into your active theme folder `/woocommerce/order/order-details-customer.php` This will only change the text in view order page.

```
<?php
/**
 * Order Customer Details
 *
 * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/order/order-details-customer.php.
 *
 * HOWEVER, on occasion WooCommerce will need to update template files and you
 * (the theme developer) will need to copy the new files to your theme to
 * maintain compatibility. We try to do this as little as possible, but it does
 * happen. When this occurs the version of the template file will be bumped and
 * the readme will list any important changes.
 *
 * @see     https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/
 * @package WooCommerce/Templates
 * @version 3.4.4
 */

defined( 'ABSPATH' ) || exit;

$show_shipping = ! wc_ship_to_billing_address_only() && $order->needs_shipping_address();
?>
<section class="woocommerce-customer-details">

    <?php if ( $show_shipping ) : ?>

    <section class="woocommerce-columns woocommerce-columns--2 woocommerce-columns--addresses col2-set addresses">
        <div class="woocommerce-column woocommerce-column--1 woocommerce-column--billing-address col-1">

    <?php endif; ?>

    <h2 class="woocommerce-column__title"><?php esc_html_e( 'Shipping address', 'woocommerce' ); ?></h2>

    <address>
        <?php echo wp_kses_post( $order->get_formatted_billing_address( esc_html__( 'N/A', 'woocommerce' ) ) ); ?>

        <?php if ( $order->get_billing_phone() ) : ?>
            <p class="woocommerce-customer-details--phone"><?php echo esc_html( $order->get_billing_phone() ); ?></p>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php if ( $order->get_billing_email() ) : ?>
            <p class="woocommerce-customer-details--email"><?php echo esc_html( $order->get_billing_email() ); ?></p>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </address>

    <?php if ( $show_shipping ) : ?>

        </div><!-- /.col-1 -->

        <div class="woocommerce-column woocommerce-column--2 woocommerce-column--shipping-address col-2">
            <h2 class="woocommerce-column__title"><?php esc_html_e( 'Shipping address', 'woocommerce' ); ?></h2>
            <address>
                <?php echo wp_kses_post( $order->get_formatted_shipping_address( esc_html__( 'N/A', 'woocommerce' ) ) ); ?>
            </address>
        </div><!-- /.col-2 -->

    </section><!-- /.col2-set -->

    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_order_details_after_customer_details', $order ); ?>

</section>
```